# Can I finally get an .AAB file format from MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

Hello internet people.

I am trying to publish an android app using MAUI to playStore for testing. After reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/overview), I however keep getting an APK file, but I actually need an .AAB file.

What can I do to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: The process in the docs should produce both an aab and an apk file, that is not the case? What does your output look like and what is the command you're running?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I actually saw the .apk file in the bin/debug/net6.0-android of the project. I saw the Signed.apk and an .apk. I did not get the .AAB

Comment: Try a release build, I think it might only show up for that. If you want to release to the Google Play Store you'll need a release build anyway

Comment: [The Documentation - Publish section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/overview#publish) says: _"Publishing builds the app, and then **copies the aab and apk files to the bin\Release\net6.0-android\publish folder**. There are two aab files, one unsigned and another signed. The signed variant has -signed in the file name."_ (emphasis by me)

Comment: Thanks, Gerald & Fildor, I will explain the steps If it works.

Comment: Thanks again @GeraldVersluis

Now I am having a problem with the google play store. The error is below:

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode. Find out more about signing.
The Android App Bundle was not signed.

Any idea what to do? or should I ask the question?

Comment: @Fildor  your help is appreciated too

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [Gerald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506387/gerald-versluis) and [Fildor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor) in the comments to the question.

I have to update the Maui Project Properties, almost like it is done in the Xamarin [counterpart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/587298/how-to-package-my-xamarinforms-project-to-aab-file.html).

Below are the steps I took:

Open your solution explorer to the MAUI project
[image: Open the solution explorer to the project]

Right click on the solution and go to properties
[image]

Go to the Android/Properties in the menu
[image]

Set the solutions to Bundles before following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/overview)

After which I got the .aab files
[image]