# Cannot upload MAUI file to Playstore due to signing in released mode

Tags: c#, android, keystore, maui, .net-maui

Hello internet people,

I followed the Maui publication [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/overview)

I got the aab file by following this [process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72487537/9337608)

The results I got are:

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode. Find out more about signing. The Android App Bundle was not signed.

[image]

What can I do to get this right?

Comment: Make sure you also followed this part of the Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/overview#create-a-keystore-file and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/overview#add-a-reference-to-the-keystore-file

Comment: I'm having the same issue.. Did you find a solution for this? I did everything according to the documentation. @gerald-versluis

Comment: Did you guys get this working? I am having the same problem. I do compile in Release mode (dotnet publish --configuration Release)

Answer (score 1):

**Check if you did not forget the `/p:AndroidKeyStore=True` if you are building from command line!**

My builds started being signed by the debug key even in release after a MSBuild update.

The command I used for building:

```
dotnet build -c Release 
             -f net7.0-android33.0
             /p:ApplicationVersion=1 
             /p:ApplicationDisplayVersion=test 
             /p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=mypass
             /p:AndroidSigningStorePass=mypass
             /p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=my.keystore
             /p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=key
```

This worked great in `MSBuild version 17.5.0-preview-23061-01+040e2a90e`. The aab was signed with the specified key.

But with `MSBuild version 17.5.1+f6fdcf537` my release builds suddenly started being signed with the debug key. After analysing the verbose logs I found out that `AndroidKeyStore` must be set to `true` for your custom key to be considered. I don't know whether this parameter was newly added or whether it was buggy and not considered before.

After I added the `AndroidKeyStore` parameter the signature was correct.

```
dotnet build -c Release 
             -f net7.0-android33.0
             /p:AndroidKeyStore=True     <--- add this
             /p:ApplicationVersion=1 
             /p:ApplicationDisplayVersion=test 
             /p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=mypass
             /p:AndroidSigningStorePass=mypass
             /p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=my.keystore
             /p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=key
```

Comment: Not sure how we missed this, but -p:AndroidKeyStore=True was missing from our command, and adding it in fixed our issue too. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need to compile in Release mode
[release mode compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAqjz.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same issue.

Whether I sign via running Visual Studio in Release mode, from the command line, or even from my Azure CI pipeline, Google Play won't let me upload the signed Android App Bundle.

By the way, if you're looking to generate a signed .aab from your Azure build pipeline, I recommend the following:

https://www.andreasnesheim.no/setting-up-ci-for-your-net-maui-android-app-in-azure-devops/

You can then hookup the signed .aab artifact to a release pipeline that pushes to Google Play by doing something like:

https://damienaicheh.github.io/azure/devops/2021/10/25/configure-azure-devops-google-play-en.html

Well, that is what I'm trying to do, at least. To my understanding, you first need to create a manual release from Google Play in order for your release pipeline to be able to find where to deploy your app. This is why I'm running into the issue above.

Any future updates on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone I had the same error and was close to giving up, when I found the problem.

DOUBLE CHECK FOR ANY TYPOS.

My problem was, that I wrote "AndroidSignedKeyStore" instead of "AndroidSigningKeyStore" in .csproj.

You wont get any compilation errors or anything, so its worth checking if you have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

in your csproj make sure that the target framework matches your PropertyGroup condition.

```
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android33.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

the condition needs to match to have the signing key (in the property group) applied

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-android33.0|AnyCPU'">
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```